# IE Google Map not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am trying to implement google maps in an application where I specify height and width wrt to percentage. In chrome and firefox it's working but when I try the same in IE the map area is grey. 
Can some one suggest how can I fix it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:500%"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=api_key&callback=myMap"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably not a great idea to display your API key...

Comment: Thanks @AlexWillison Will note the same next time

Comment: Are you using IE 10?

Comment: IE 11 version: 11.0.41

Comment: Can you try   `Turn off Compatibility view` and check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the height to a fixed number of pixels, for example 500px, if that works we know the problem is there so then just set the `html` and `body` height to 100% and go back to your 500% height on your map div.

This happens in IE because when you want to use percentages for height, all the preceding elements in your hierarchy must have a set height as well.

Answer (score 0):

remove the comma after zoom. you can also write your properties like that:

```
var mapProp= {
    center: { lat: 51.508742, lng: ,-0.120850}
    zoom:5
};
```

Maybe this helps. Otherwise, just set height to 500% and look if that works. I use gmaps in IE and it works perfectly

cheers

Comment: It didn't solve. I tried changing both mapProp and also changed the width but, no use.